# Failed building wheel for macs3

Tags: python

Failed to build macs3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for macs3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

No idea how to troubleshoot it. any help is appreciated

Comment: please include the full error message, your python version and operating system. Also share the command you ran for the installation. The text you ahve provided is simply a summary saying that something went wrong. It does not contain any information to troubleshoot